# Learning to work with Arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to simplify a project I have worked and have hit a wall.  The intent is to take input from a .txt file and enter it into an array based on types of employees.  Then take that data and calculate the salaries (calculations handled in other classes for each type) and output the information and an average salary for that year.  I am being told that I only place one type (Executive) in the array in this code, but I don't see anything different in that method vs the rest.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Salaries{
   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
   final DecimalFormat Currency = new DecimalFormat("$0,000.00");
   final DecimalFormat Percentage = new DecimalFormat("0.00%");  
   String fileName = "data1.txt";
   Scanner fileScanner;  
   int count2014=0;
   int count2015=0;
Employee [] data2014 = new Employee[10];
Employee [] data2015 = new Employee[10];
   try{   
   fileScanner=new Scanner(new File(fileName));
       while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
           String nextEmployee = fileScanner.nextLine();
           String[]data=(nextEmployee.split(" "));
           Employee employee = null;
               if (data[1].equals ("Employee")){
                   String name=data[2];
                   double salary=Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
               if (data[0].equals("2014")){
                   employee=new Employee(name, salary);
                   employee=data2014[2];
                   count2014++;
               }
               else{
                  employee=new Employee(name,salary);
                  employee=data2015[2];
                  count2015++;
                }
            }
           else if (data[1].equals ("OnCommission")){
                    String name=data[2];
                    double salary=Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                    double commission=Double.parseDouble(data[4]);
                    double sales=Double.parseDouble(data[5]);
               if (data[0].equals("2014")){
                   data2014[count2014]=new EmployeeOnCommission(name, salary, commission, sales);
                   count2014++;
               }
               else{
                  data2015[count2015]=new EmployeeOnCommission(name,salary, commission, sales);
                  count2015++;
                }
           }
           else if (data[1].equals ("Executive")){
                    String name=data[2];
                    double salary=Double.parseDouble(data[3]);
                    double stock=Double.parseDouble(data[4]);
                if (data[0].equals("2014")){
                    data2014[count2014]=new Executive(name, salary, stock);
                    count2014++;
                }
                else{
                    data2015[count2015]=new Executive(name, salary, stock);
                    count2015++;
                }
           }
       }
}
catch (FileNotFoundException | NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println(e);
}



  double avgOf2014=0;
//Results of the 2014 year employees data
  System.out.println("Year - 2014 : ");
   for(int i = 0; i < count2014; i++){
       System.out.print(data2014[i].toString()+
       " Annual Salary: " +data2014[i].annualSalary()); 
       avgOf2014+=data2014[i].annualSalary();
   }      
   //average of 2014 salaries
   System.out.println("Average of 2014 salaries: "
               +Currency.format(avgOf2014/(count2014)));
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

You can't store two different types of objects on one array. Unless your Executive class extends Employee.

You can't still do this:

```
ChildClass[] child = new ChildClass[10];
ParentClass[] parent = child;
parent[0]=new ParentClass();
```

You need to do this:

```
ChildClass[] child = new ChildClass[10];
ParentClass[] parent = child;
parent[0]=new ChildClass();
```

I also noticed a issue with your code below,

```
if (data[0].equals("2014")){
    employee=new Employee(name, salary);
    employee=data2014[2];
    count2014++;
```

In the above bit of code, you create a new Employee object and then immediately overwrite it's reference with data2014[2]. You should replace it with,

```
if (data[0].equals("2014")){
    employee=new Employee(name, salary);
    data2014[count2014] = employee;
    count2014++;
```

Comment: Executive does, in fact extend Employee.  I can post those classes too if it would help.  I was trying not to have others do the work for me, just point me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks!  That advice worked perfectly.  Makes sense why I was seeing NullPointerExceptions.  I was overwriting the references.